# how to compare the result from rstan with the result from survreg

Tags: r, bayesian, survival-analysis, stan, rstan

I performed both a classic survival analysis with the function `survreg()` from the `survival` package, and a bayesian analysis with `rstan`. I believe that there is no significant difference between the two approaches. So, how to transform the result of `rstan` to obtain an output similar to the result of the frequentist approach?
The data is from the `survival` package. The code is as follows:

```r
#rm(list=ls())
library(survival)
data_for_Stan <- list(n_cen = with(ovarian,sum(fustat)),
                      n_not_cen = with(ovarian,sum(1 - fustat)),
                      t_cen = with(ovarian,futime[fustat == 1]),
                      t_not_cen = with(ovarian,futime[fustat == 0]),
                      x_cen = ovarian %>% mutate(intercept = 1) %>% 
                        filter(fustat == 1) %>% 
                        dplyr::select(intercept,ecog.ps,rx),            
                      x_not_cen = ovarian %>% mutate(intercept = 1) %>% 
                        filter(fustat == 0) %>% 
                        dplyr::select(intercept,ecog.ps,rx),
                      K= 3)                            

##Model with Bayessian framework
library(rstan)
Bayesian_model <- 
  "
data {
 int < lower = 1 > n_cen;
 int < lower = 1 > n_not_cen; 
 int < lower = 1 > K;
 vector[n_cen] t_cen; 
 vector[n_not_cen] t_not_cen;
 matrix[n_cen,K] x_cen; 
 matrix[n_not_cen,K] x_not_cen;
}

parameters {
 vector[K] beta; 
 real < lower = 0 > rho; 
}

model {
to_vector(beta) ~ normal(0,100^2);
target += cauchy_lpdf(rho|1.0, 10.0); 
target += weibull_lpdf(t_not_cen | rho, exp(x_not_cen * beta));
target += weibull_lccdf(t_cen | rho, exp(x_cen * beta));
}

"
write(Bayesian_model,file = "Bayesian_model.stan") 

fit_predict = stan(file = "Bayesian_model.stan", 
                   data = data_for_Stan, warmup = 1000, 
                   iter = 2000, chains = 4, 
                   cores = 2, thin = 1) 

fit <- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx, ovarian, dist='weibull')

fit_predict
summary(fit)$table
```

my motivation is from the work of Julia Stander et al. (A Bayesian Survival Analysis of a Historical Dataset: How Long Do Popes Live?The American Statistician,2017)

My Bayesian model is:

```r
T_i ~ Weibull(rho, mu_i)
log(mu_i) = X * beta
beta ~ normal(0,100^2)
rho ~ cauchy(1,10)
```